# Not able to install Fuchsia on LINUX

Tags: linux, operating-system, fuchsia

I am trying to install `Fuchsia` using the installation guide given by Google from [here](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/docs/+/HEAD/getting_started.md).

I was able to run the first command.
Prepare your build environment (Once per build environment)

sudo apt-get install texinfo libglib2.0-dev liblz4-tool autoconf libtool libsdl-dev build-essential golang git curl unzip

We need to get the source to build Fuchsia, and by running the below command I am getting the error which is because of server.

```
prashant@prashant-Lenovo:~$ curl -s "https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/scripts/+/master/bootstrap?format=TEXT" | base64 --decode | bash -s topaz
Please add /home/prashant/fuchsia/.jiri_root/bin to your PATH
WARN: Please opt in or out of analytics collection. You will receive this warning until an option is selected.
To check what data we collect run 'jiri init -show-analytics-data'
To opt-in run 'jiri init -analytics-opt=true "/home/prashant/fuchsia"'
To opt-out run 'jiri init -analytics-opt=false "/home/prashant/fuchsia"'

WARN: Please opt in or out of analytics collection. You will receive this warning until an option is selected.
To check what data we collect run 'jiri init -show-analytics-data'
To opt-in run 'jiri init -analytics-opt=true "/home/prashant/fuchsia"'
To opt-out run 'jiri init -analytics-opt=false "/home/prashant/fuchsia"'

Updating all projects
ERROR: 'git clone --no-checkout https://dart.googlesource.com/sdk /home/prashant/fuchsia/third_party/dart' failed:
Cloning into '/home/prashant/fuchsia/third_party/dart'...
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed

command fail error: exit status 128

Wait for 5s before next attempt...: Cloning https://dart.googlesource.com/sdk

ERROR: 'git clone --no-checkout https://skia.googlesource.com/skia /home/prashant/fuchsia/third_party/skia' failed:
Cloning into '/home/prashant/fuchsia/third_party/skia'...
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed

command fail error: exit status 128
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This looks git communication error, do check the following things,

- You have git updated version
- Your get configuration (user.name, user.email) are set
- You do have Google account access